# Why does the universal cover of $SL_{2}(\mathbb{R})$ have no finite-dimensional representations?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras, lie-groups

Why does the universal cover of $SL_{2}(\mathbb{R})$ have no finite-dimensional representations?

Comment: It hasn't? I could perhaps believe it has no _faithful_ finite-dimensional representation, though.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here's a slightly different way of seeing that $\DeclareMathOperator{\SL}{SL(2,\mathbb{R})}\DeclareMathOperator{\USL}{\widetilde{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})}\DeclareMathOperator{\SLC}{SL(2,\mathbb{C})}\DeclareMathOperator{\sl}{\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{R})}\DeclareMathOperator{\slc}{\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})}\USL$ has no faithful finite-dimensional representations:

Start with a representation $\Phi$ of $\USL$ on a finite-dimensional real vector space. The associated representation $\phi=d\Phi(1)$ of $\sl$ can be complexified to yield a representation of $\slc$. Since $\SLC$ is simply connected, this corresponds to a representation $\Psi_{\mathbb{C}}$ of $\SLC$. Since $\SL$  is a subgroup of $\SLC$, we get a representation $\Psi$ of $\SL$. The covering projection $\pi:\USL \to \SL$ yields another representation $\Psi\circ\pi$ of $\USL$. It is straightforward to check that $\phi = \psi$ ($= d(\Psi\circ\pi)(1)$). Since $\USL$ is simply connected, this means that $\Phi$ and $\Psi\circ\pi$ are actually the same representation. This shows that $\Phi$ factors over $\pi$, and hence has non-trivial kernel.

Comment: To show that $d\Phi(1) = d(\Psi \circ \pi)(1)$, is it just $d(\Psi \circ \pi)(1) = d\Psi(1)\circ d\pi(1) = d\Psi(1) = d\Phi(1)$ where the last equality is because of how $\Psi$ is defined?

Comment: Yes, exactly.${}$

Comment: By the way the same argument applies to every non trivial cover of $SL(2\mathbb{R})$, since morphisms of connected Lie groups are determined by their differential at the identity (even without simply connectedness).

Answer (score 9):

I don't have a deep answer -- just a proof.

First, I assume you want to know why $\widetilde{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ has no finite-dimensional *faithful* representations, i.e. why it cannot be expressed as a matrix group.

The proof is that the Lie algebra of $\widetilde{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ is $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{R})$, so any representation of $\widetilde{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ must induce a representation of $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{R})$ at the tangent space to the identity.  Moreover, since $\widetilde{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ is simply connected, the representation of $\widetilde{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ is entirely determined by the representation of $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{R})$.

Now, the representations of $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{R})$ have been completely classified, and it is easy to check that none of them induce a faithful representation of $\widetilde{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$.  So that's that.

On a more philosophical level, there's no reason to think that every Lie group would be a matrix group, so it's not surprising that $\widetilde{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ turns out not to be.  This happens a lot for covers of matrix groups.  For example, the universal covers of the [symplectic groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_group) are the [metaplectic groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaplectic_group), which also have no faithful finite-dimensional representations.

Comment: Instead of using the classification of representations you can complexify to a representation of $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C})$ and use that $SL_2(\mathbb{C})$ is simply connected to get a representation of $SL_2(\mathbb{C})$. This restricts to a representation of $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$ and you can precompose this new one with the covering projection of $\widetilde{SL}_2(\mathbb{R}) \to SL_2(\mathbb{R})$. Then you can check on the level of Lie algebras that nothing happened, that is every representation of $\widetilde{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ factors over a representation of $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: @t.b. Yes, that is a nice way to see it.  Why not post it as your own answer?

Comment: Okay, done. I haven't checked right now, but I think similar arguments work in the other non-matrix groups you mentioned.

Comment: It may be worth pointing out that every *compact* Lie group is a matrix group, but that the proof is nontrivial.

Answer (score 5):

This comes a bit late but I think it answers shortly the question:

**Theorem:** Any connected linear semisimple Lie group has finite center.

(This is mainly because of Schur's Lemma)

But $Z(\widetilde{SL_2(\mathbb{R})})$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$ the fundamental group of $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: Could you explain why the center of the universal cover is equal to the fundamental group?

Comment: @Nighthap I will just send you a post that have a detailed answer (look at the first answer). https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2982407/universal-cover-of-sl-2-mathbbr-and-metaplectic-group/2982472?noredirect=1#comment6167691_2982472