# Is there a non-matrix Lie group?

Tags: lie-groups

I'm new to Lie Groups, but all the examples I found are matrix groups. Can someone show a non-matrix Lie group?

Comment: Example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaplectic_group. Proof that $\mathrm{Mp}(2, \Bbb R)$ is not a matrix group: http://concretenonsense.wordpress.com/2009/07/10/a-lie-group-which-isnt-a-matrix-group/.

Comment: See also this related discussion on MO: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/64195/when-is-a-finite-dimensional-real-or-complex-lie-group-not-a-matrix-group

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/129644

Answer (score 10):

There are no non-matrix Lie groups whose dimension is $1$ or $2$. On the other hand, consider the quotient of the Heisenberg group$$\left\{\begin{pmatrix}1&a&c\\0&1&b\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}\,\middle|\,a,b,c\in\mathbb R\right\}$$by the normal subgroup$$\left\{\begin{pmatrix}1&0&m\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}\,\middle|\,m\in\mathbb Z\right\}.$$It is a non-matrix three-dimensional Lie group.

Answer (score 5):

There is the [metaplactic group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaplectic_group), which is the unique connected double cover of the symplectic group.

Answer (score 3):

Lie groups are smooth manifolds. They may or may not have matrix representations. For example, the [universal cover of $\mathbf{SL}_2(\mathbf{R})$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SL2(R)#Topology_and_universal_cover) is a Lie group that is not a matrix Lie group.

Answer (score 0):

In Hall 2015 Definition 1.20 there is following example of a nonmatrix lie group:
Let
$$G= \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \times S^1 =\{(x,y,u)|x\in \mathbb{R}, y \in \mathbb{R}, u \in S^1\subset\mathbb{C}\}$$
Be a group with group Operation
$$(x_1,y_1,u_1)\cdot(x_2,y_2,u_2)= (x_1+x_2, y_1+y_2,e^{i x_1y_2}u_1u_2) $$
Then G has the following proprieties

- G is associative as you can check.
- It has an Identity $e = (0,0,1)$.
- It has an inverse $(-x,-y,e^{ixy}u^{-1})$.
- It is a manifold beucause as defined above G is a cylinder.
- The group operations are smooth.

So G is a lie Group.

Comment: This is the same example as the one given by José Carlos Santos over 6 years earlier.