# Is there a non-matrix complex Lie groups?

Tags: lie-groups, algebraic-groups

From [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/206117/is-there-a-non-matrix-lie-group), we have some non-matrix Lie groups, but all of them are real Lie groups, is there a non-matrix **complex** Lie group? Or a complex Lie group which is not a linear algebraic group?

Comment: How about $\mathbb{C}^{n}$ with addition?

Comment: @See-Woo Lee $\mathbb{C}$ is naturally isomorphism with the 2×2 upper triangular unipotent group I+$\mathbb{C}$e$_{12}$, do the direct sum by n copies, we get $\mathbb{C}$$^n$ as a matrix Lie group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take an elliptic curve over the complex numbers. It is a complex Lie group, however it can not be a matrix Lie group because any matrix Lie group is affine and elliptic curves are projective.

Comment: Very nice example! Can we say that all holomorphic maps from a connected compact complex manifold to $\mathbb{C}$ are constant?

Comment: Dear @orangeskid, I think the best idea would be to ask that as a separate question. Cheers!