# Lie Algebra homomorphism from $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{R})$ to $\mathfrak{gl}(m,\mathbb{R})$ is the derivtive of a unique Lie group homomorphism

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, topological-groups

I want to show that every lie algebra homomorphism $\phi$: $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \mathfrak{gl}(m,\mathbb{R})$ is the derivtive of a unique Lie group homomorphism $\Phi: Sl(2,\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow GL(m,\mathbb{R})$ at the identity ie
$$ \phi = T_e\Phi $$
I know that the statement would be true if $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ was simply connected.

I think the uniqueness should work like that:

Since $\Phi(\exp(X)) = \exp(\phi(X))$ for all $X \in \mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{R}), \Phi$ is uniquely determined on an open neighborhood of $e$. Because $GL(2,\mathbb{R})$ is path-connected, any open neighborhood generates $G$, so $\Phi$ is unique if it exists.

Existence seems a lot harder$\ldots$

I think there has to be a shortcut that I am missing.

The hint says: “consider the relation between $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{R})$ and $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$.”

Any help would be much appreciated. :)

Comment: A priori you only get a map from the universal cover of $SL_2$ to the universal cover of $GL_m$ (and neither is simply connected). I don't know what the intended solution is here but you can do this by just classifying all finite-dimensional representations of $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{R})$ and just checking directly that they all exponentiate to representations of $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Complexifying $\phi$ gives a Lie algebra homomorphism $\mathfrak{sl}(2, \mathbb C) \to  \mathfrak{gl}(m, \mathbb C)$. Because $\operatorname{SL}(2, \mathbb C)$ is simply connected, this one does lift to the groups and restricting gives a Lie group homomorphism $\operatorname{SL}(2, \mathbb R) \to \operatorname{GL}(m, \mathbb C)$ with derivative $\phi$. The image is generated by $\exp$ of a neighborhood of $0$ in $\mathfrak{gl}(m, \mathbb R)$, so it lands in $\operatorname{GL}(m, \mathbb R)$.

This is related:
[Why does the universal cover of $SL_{2}(\mathbb{R})$ have no finite-dimensional representations?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/129644/why-does-the-universal-cover-of-sl-2-mathbbr-have-no-finite-dimensional?noredirect=1&lq=1)

The alternative proof, as in the comment, is to use that all irreducible representations of $\mathfrak{sl}(2, \mathbb R)$ are symmetric powers of the standard representation, and all representations are sums of irreducibles, so they all lift to the group because the standard representation does.