# Defining the exponential of a Lie algebra of a Lie group.

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

I am struggling to understand how to find the form of the exponential map of the lie algebra of a lie group. That is: given a Lie group $G$ such that $T_1G$ is it's Lie algebra (which is isomorphic to the space of left invariant vector fields) how do we define the exponential $$e^{tX}, \quad X \in T_1G$$
I know for linear groups this exponential map is just the matrix exponential. However for a general Lie group this is unclear.

Comment: By Ado's theorem you may assume that the Lie algebra is a matrix algebra. Then $\exp(A)=I+\frac{1}{1!}A+\frac{1}{2!}A^2+ \cdots $ as you said. For the general case see Warner's book, see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_map_(Lie_theory)).

Comment: @DietrichBurde If $G$ is connected does this imply that $exp(...)$ generates $G$ meaning that $G$ is a linear group?

Comment: No, not every connected Lie group is linear, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/122612/non-linear-lie-groups).

Comment: I believe it is true that $\exp(\mathfrak{g})$ generates $G$ in that every element of $G$ can be written as a product of finitely many elements of the image of $\exp$. However, for non-compact groups, it is *not* generally true that $\exp$ is surjective. Determining the image of $\exp$ in small examples such as $SL(2, \mathbb{R})$ is already quite interesting! All this completely orthogonal to the question of whether or not the group is linear so maybe I misunderstand your question (in the comments)